# How to apply CSS style to select box after option is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML form that I'm trying to style using Bootstrap and my own CSS rules.  The form has six pulldown (select) elements.  When I load the form, I want to ensure that each pulldown has a certain background and font color that looks like this:

[image: initial-select]

When I click the pulldown to select an option, I want the background color and font color to stay the same.  But my CSS and JavaScript isn't causing that to happen. Instead, the font color is a darker gray.  Also, bright blue outline appears around the pulldown element that I don't want:

[image: after-select]

I don't get the styling I want on the pulldown I just clicked until I click on the next pulldown:

[image: mouseout]

How do I get the pulldown box to look like what you see in the third image immediately after I select an option in the pulldown instead of having to wait until I click the next pulldown?  Also, how do I get rid of that bright blue outline at that same time?

Here is the pulldown element:

```
<select name="person_height" class="form-control" id="id_person_height"
style="background: rgb(57,63,77);">
  <option value selected>--------</option>
  <option value="2">Under 4'10"</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
select.form-control {
  color: $form-font-color;   // Sass variable
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
// Global
var formBgColor = '#393f4d';
var formFontColor = '#f0f0f0';

function setFormFieldColors() {
    var selectEls = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectEls.length; i++) {
        selectEls[i].style.background = formBgColor;
        selectEls[i].click(function () {
            selectEls[i].style.backgroundColor = formBgColor;
            selectEls[i].style.color = formFontColor;
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a focus style:

```
<style>
    select.form-control:focus {
       color: #f0f0f0;
       border: none;
    }
</style>
```